# MAGENTO: Front end catalog product images disappeared

Tags: magento

i have issues with my magento site, firstly, my site was not working so i restored the site with my latest backup. everything is working fine but the catalaog images in the frontend is not working. I guess the magento is not rebuilding the cache for the images. but i can see the products images in the backend side.

can anyone suggest me wat may be the solution. 
thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at the permission of your `/media/cache/images` folder. Also did you do a reindexing of your catalog?

Comment: yes i did reindexing of catalog